# Why does Rome think my file is empty when I try to compile it?

Tags: javascript, toolchain, romejs

I'm trying out this new thing from Facebook called [`Rome`](https://romejs.dev/)

As it is still experimental, you need to first build this tool from source. I followed these [steps](https://github.com/facebookexperimental/rome/issues/30) without any issues.

In a nutshell, what I did was:

```sh
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/facebookexperimental/rome.git
cd rome
./scripts/build-release dist
```

I then installed it with:

```sh
cd /tmp
mkdir try-rome
cd try-rome/
npm install ../rome/dist/
```

That was all fine. I then created this file `index.js` with the following content:

```js
alert("wat?")
```

And put an empty `rome.json` file at the root as per the ["Getting Started"](https://romejs.dev/docs/introduction/getting-started/) instructions at time of writing:

> Rome requires a project configuration in order to operate. This can take three possible forms.
>
> - A rome.json file
> - A rome.rjson file (What is RJSON? See #13)
> - A rome field on package.json
>
> This can just be an empty file. It's required in order for Rome to determine all the files in a project

And ran this command:

```sh
./node_modules/.bin/rome compile index.js
```

Which failed with the following error:

[image]

I know this file isn't empty so why does Rome think it is?

Comment: try to write an empty json inside rome.json i.e. `{}`

Comment: @V.Sambor That was it! Many thanks. I guess I took the `This can just be an empty file.` message too literally ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://romejs.dev/docs/introduction/getting-started/) I saw this line:

```
$ echo '{}' >rome.json
```

It seems like the `rome.json` file should have at least an empty json `{}`

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that. I think the doc are confusing. I'll raise an issue.

Comment: Yeah, most confusing for me is why they need another format `rjson` does not make any sense...

Answer (score 1):

In this context an empty `rome.json` file means it has at least `{}`. I agree the docs should reword this to make it more clear.

The better way to generate the `rome.json` file which will result in less issues is to use the `./scripts/dev-rome init` script which gives a recommended configuration that enables linting.